# how to get cubes to change to black when mouse moves over them

Tags: javascript

how does one get the cubes made in the grid to turn black with mouse running over? any help would be appreciated.

```
function Grid(z) {
    for (y=0; y < z; y++) {
        for (x=0; x < z; x++) {
            size = 700 / z;
            var div = document.querySelector('#container');
            var block = document.createElement('div');
            block.style.height = size + 'px';
            block.style.width = size + 'px';
            block.classList.add('cube');

            div.appendChild(block);
        }
    }      
}

function changeBlockColor() {
    Grid(16);

    var s = document.querySelector('.cube');
    s.addEventListener('onmouseover', function(){
        s.setAttribute('style', 'background: black');
    });
}

changeBlockColor();
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use CSS to achieve this effect.

```
.cube {
  background-color:red;
}
.cube:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is for if you want the cubes to **stay black** after you finished hovering over them (and then hovered out).

First, your `s = document.querySelector('.cube');` will make `s` **only point to the first element** with class `cube`. To solve that, make `s` an array of all elements of class `cube`, by using `s = document.querySelectorAll('.cube');` instead.

Next, you need to loop through the array s and add the event listener to all its elements:

```js
for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  s[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    this.setAttribute('style', 'background: black');
  });
}
```

Notice the use of `this` inside the handler. Inside handler code, `this` refers to the object that triggered the event (the cube moused over in your case).

Comment: If you want them to be black only when mouse is over the element, and then revert to original color on mouse leave, pure CSS can achieve that as pointed out by Paul Thomas' answer.

Answer (score 1):

The event name you want is `mouseover`, not `onmouseover`

Also, `querySelector` will only find the first matching element, so you need to use `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByClassName` instead

Finally, you need to iterate over all the elements you matched, which are returned in an `Object`, not an `Array`, so you need to use a `for` loop.

#### Solution

```js
function createGrid(z) {
    for (var y = 0; y < z; ++y) {
        for (var x = 0; x < z; ++x) {
            var size = 700 / z;
            var div = document.getElementById('container');
            var block = document.createElement('div');

            block.style.height = size + 'px';
            block.style.width = size + 'px';
            block.classList.add('cube');

            div.appendChild(block);
        }
    }
    changeBlockColor()
}

function changeBlockColor(){
  var cubes = document.querySelectorAll('.cube')

  for (var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
    cubes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
      e.target.classList.add('active')
    })
  }
}
createGrid(16);
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.cube {
  background-color: red;
}
.active {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

#### Implementation Details

- Naming is all preference in JS, but traditionally, names that start with a capital letter are for a `class`, so I renamed you function to `createGrid`
- At the end of `createGrid` I call `changeBlockColor`, rather than call `createGrid` from inside `changeBlockColor`, logically it make more sense.
- I created a CSS class called `active` to handle changing the color, as using `setAttribute('style')` was erasing the `height` and `width` styles you applied inside you `Grid` function.

#### Feedback

- You use `querySelector` exclusively, you should get to know `getElementById` as well.
- You use `var` a few times, but don't declare `y`, `x`, or `size`
- You can define `y` and `x` in your `for` loop with `for(var y=0` and `for(var x=0`

#### CSS Solution

Assuming you want the color to revert on `mouseout`, you can achieve this same effect with CSS using `.cube:hover`

```css
.cube {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
.cube:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
<div class="cube"></div>
```

#### Performance

A side note about using `querySelector('#container')` vs `getElementById('container')`. The first has to traverse the entire DOM looking for the selector, the latter can just go to the internal list of ids and return the reference.

https://jsperf.com/so53824751

#### Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: your code won't work if the grid of cube is completed later; Your QueryselectorAll will return no element, and the new div.cube won't have any  event listener.

Comment: no matter about DOMContentLoaded considerations. Its function (function Grid (z)) must be called dynamically by its user to build this grid

Answer (score 1):

No need to have hundred of mouseover Event Listener. Just one is enough

```js
var
  divContainer = document.getElementById('container'),
  CubeClass    = 'cube';

function Grid(z)
{
  var sizePx = Math.floor(700 / z) + 'px';
  for (let y = 0; y < z; y++)
  {
    for (let x = 0; x < z; x++)
    {
      let block          = document.createElement('div');
      block.style.height = sizePx;
      block.style.width  = sizePx;
      block.className    = CubeClass;
      divContainer.appendChild(block);
    };
  };
}
divContainer.onmouseover = function(e)
{
  if (!e.target.classList.contains( CubeClass )) return;
  e.target.setAttribute('style', 'background: black');
}

divContainer.onmouseout = function(e)   // if you need it...
{
  if (!e.target.classList.contains( CubeClass )) return;
  e.target.removeAttribute('style');
}
```

Comment: `const` and `let` aren't supported in IE 10 and under. Also, `let` isn't properly supported inside `for` loops in IE11. For web solutions, you should just stick with `var` and leave ES6 for the NodeJS.

Comment: @ AnonymousSB : if it suits you better, but honestly do you really think that this solution is so bad ?

Comment: I didn't say it's bad, it's pretty clever actually, I'm just giving feedback about browser support. Honestly though, using CSS is the best solution for this particular situation. You don't need to worry about code execution order, and it's much faster.

Comment: Some optimization feedback though, I'd use `getElementById('container') instead of `querySelector('#container')` and slap a `var` on your `size` variable.

Comment: At first, I think his question is about a paint application. He does not want to remove the black color, but maybe later replace it with another color taken on a pallette of colors.
Then afterwards erases all the grid to replace it with another virgin, having all its cubes in a different size